# Gitlab protected branch

Tags: git, gitlab

So i have setup selfhosted gitlab(version 14.8.2-ee).
It works fine, except i can't make "protected branch" rules work.
I've got this rule: [Protected branch rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogX1U.png)
And it works, if i am trying to create file directly into master branch from gitlab web GUI.
But if i am pushing from my PC using git CLI, gitlab dose not reject it!
What am i missing?

```
git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 217 bytes | 217.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://<gitlab url>/root/test-push-problems.git
   489072e..2be97ad  master -> master
```

Comment: What username did you use in git push? Is the username allowed to directly push?

Comment: No one allowed to push(look at the screenshot), and user is not an admin user.
User is added to repository as developer.

Comment: In the log, `git push` did not ask you for username and password(token). It seems `credential.helper` is enabled and the username and password have been cached by the helper. The cached username is probably an admin. And double check if they are the same repository.

Comment: Are you by change an administrator of your GitLab instance? I noticed the namespace you're using is `root` which is the namespace of the default admin account.

Comment: I created this repository as admin this is true, but i'm using non admin user. I used different accounts to double check.

Answer (score 0):

Just restarting instance solved my problem, but i still don't know what caused it.